# Exchanging Increasing Annuity Immediate for a Perpetuity

Tags: actuarial-science

for the most part I understand this question, but i'm missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  "Dipper has a 10 year increasing annuity immediate that pays 
  $100 at the end of the first year, $200 at the end of the second 
  year, ... , and $1000 at the end of the 10th year. He exchanges 
  the annuity for a perpetuity of equal value that pays X at the 
  end of each year. If the effective annual interest rate is 3%, 
  find the value of X."
```

What I did:

Increasing Annuity Immediate = Perpetuity

100(Is)10|.03         = X/i

100[((Annuity Due) - n)/.03] = X/.03

FV Annuity Due = (1+i)[(1+i^n)-1/i] = (1.03)[((1.03)^10 - 1)/.03]

FV Annuity Due = 11.807

100[((11.807) - 10/.03]      = X/.03

6023                         = X/.03

180.7                        = X

Answer (score 1):

$$
100\;(Ia)_{\overline{10}|3\%}=\frac{X}{3\%}
$$
that is
$$
X=3\cdot\frac{\ddot a_{\overline{10}|3\%}-10v^{10}}{3\%}=100\left(\ddot a_{\overline{10}|3\%}-10v^{10}\right)=134.52
$$
where $v=\frac{1}{1.03}$ and $\ddot a_{\overline{10}|3\%}=\frac{1-v^{10}}{1-v}=8.79$

Comment: Thank you! I feel like i am missing a really simple fundamental concept here. Can you explain why you used the present value instead of the accumulated value?

Comment: Because you have an increasing annuity (now) that you want to exchange with a perpetuity (now). What you did is to accumulate a sum after 10 years (with an increasing annuity) and then to convert this sum into a perpetuity.